# Redirect loop when connecting to Gerrit

Tags: gerrit

I'm attempting to get Gerrit running behind an Apache 2.2.15 proxy and running into a redirect loop when I try to connect.  Am I missing something?

[2013-11-26 07:44:04,701] INFO  com.google.gerrit.sshd.SshDaemon : Started Gerrit SSHD on *:29418
[2013-11-26 07:44:04,706] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server : jetty-8.1.7.v20120910
/tmp/gerrit_1340818739918966007_app/gerrit_war/}
[2013-11-26 07:44:06,211] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector : Started SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:8081
[2013-11-26 07:44:06,213] INFO  com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon : Gerrit Code Review 2.8-rc2 ready

Apache Config:

```
Listen 8083
<VirtualHost *:8083>  
    ServerName host.domain.com

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Location "/gerrit/login/">
            AuthType shibboleth
            ShibRequestSetting requireSession 1
            Require valid-user
    </Location>

    RequestHeader set REMOTE_USER %{REMOTE_USER}s
    ProxyPass /gerrit/ http://localhost:8081/gerrit/

</VirtualHost>
```

gerrit config:

```
[gerrit]
    canonicalWebUrl = http://host.domain.com:8083/gerrit/
[auth]
    type = HTTP
    httpHeader = REMOTE_USER
[httpd] 
    listenUrl = proxy-http://127.0.0.1:8081/gerrit/
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things I notice in your setup

1. You try to have the `Location` on the `gerrit/login/`. This is not going to work as Gerrit will require the authentication details to be present.
2. You are missing the `AllowEncodedSlashes On` and `nocanon` statement. But I am not sure if this is only applicable to Apache 2.4 that I am using

This is part of my configuration:

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On
ReWriteEngine On

ProxyPass /gerrit http://localhost:8081/gerrit nocanon
```

Your gerrit.config looks ok.